# Method return error

Tags: c#, arrays, methods, return-type

Hi I am getting an error at return avg; saying return key must not be followed by object expression if anyone could help me with my problem I be very thankful.

```
    static void Pos(int[] array)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        float sum = 0;
        int counter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            array[i] = rand.Next(-100, 100);
            if(sum >= 0)
            {
                sum += array[i];
                counter++;
            }
            float avg = sum / counter;
            return avg; <<< error?
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot return anthing since your return type is `void`

Change this  `static void Pos(int[] array)` to  `static float Pos(int[] array)`

And also you may get "not all code path returns";

Do this:

```
static float Pos(int[] array)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        float sum = 0;
        int counter = 0;
        float avg;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            array[i] = rand.Next(-100, 100);
            if(sum >= 0)
            {
                sum += array[i];
                counter++;
            }
            avg = sum / counter;
        }
        return avg;
    }
```

Comment: I did that then I get a error at static void >>> Pos <<< saing not all code path can be returned what do i do to that?

Answer (score 1):

Your method's return type is `void`, and you are returning a value from it.

Do it like this:

```
static float Pos(int[] array)
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    float sum = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    float avg = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        array[i] = rand.Next(-100, 100);
        if(sum >= 0)
        {
            sum += array[i];
            counter++;
        }
        avg = sum / counter;

    }
    return avg;
}
```

When you set the return type to **void**, it means you don't want the method to return anything.

Comment: I did gives me static void >>> Pos <<< error saying not all code path can be returned what do i do to that?

Comment: return form outside for loop

Answer (score 1):

You're using a void which doesn't allow you to return anything.